# Why DatePeriod instance acts like an array in foreach?

Tags: php

**Code example**

```
$start = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime();
$end->modify('+1 month');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach($period as $i => $date){
    print "$i =>";
    var_dump($date);
}
```

`$period` is an object, not array.

Why does it act like a numbered array with 4 elements? I don't understand where they come from. I `var_dump($period)` and it has 6 properties and none of them is an array with 4 elements:

```
public 'start'
public 'current'
public 'end'
public 'interval'
public 'recurrences'
public 'include_start_date'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php):

> A date period allows iteration over a set of dates and times, recurring at regular intervals, over a given period.
>
> **Class synopsis**
>
> ```
> class DatePeriod implements IteratorAggregate
> ```

It implements the iterator protocol, which allows you to iterate over it like an array.

Comment: Where does it hold this array's data? I don't see it through `var_dump`

Comment: There is no array data. It calculates the dates as it goes. Each time you iterate, it adds `interval` to `current` to get the next date.